# Is there a way to flatten (programatically) a filled in XFA PDF form so it can be opened nicely in browsers?

Tags: pdf, xfa

I have an XFA PDF that is already filled in and now I want to convert it to more compatible format so that it can be opened right in the browsers instead of showing a blank document (bad user experience).

Is there a way to maybe "flatten" (programatically) the XFA PDF so that it will be a straight-up PDF?

I'm using Java and have these imports:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBuffer;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDXFA;
```

And the code is like this:

```
File sourcePdf = new File(this.manager.getStringValue("SourcePDFFile", data));
File targetPDF = new File(this.manager.getStringValue("TargetPDFFile", data));

try {
    PDDocument e = PDDocument.load(sourcePdf);
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = e.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm form = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    PDXFA xfa = form.getXFA();
    String s = new String(xfa.getBytes());
    String replacementString = IOUtils.toString(data.getDataStream());
    s = s.replaceAll("<xfa:data />", replacementString);
    COSStream cosout = new COSStream(new RandomAccessBuffer());
    OutputStream out = cosout.createUnfilteredStream();
    out.write(s.getBytes());
    form.setXFA(new PDXFA(cosout));
    e.save(targetPDF.getAbsolutePath());
    return data;
} catch (Exception var12) {
    throw new EIPException("Filling Processor: Unable to fill PDF", var12);
}
```

Comment: Open it in Acrobat Reader and print it to a PDF printer.

Comment: I mean programatically. I'll update the question.

Comment: It looks like PDFClown might do it?

Comment: I am not aware of any open source library that can do this

Comment: Does it need to be an open source library as @yms assumes? That been asked this essentially amounts to a request to recommend a library (which can flatten XFA), and AFAIK such requests are considered OT here.

Comment: Adobe LiveCycle ES can flatten XFA forms and iText can flatten filled out XFA forms if you use the closed source [XFA Worker addon](http://itextpdf.com/product/xfa_worker). I am not aware of any other product that can do this.